# How do I pass an array into a directive without it turning into a string?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Righty, so I'm just getting into directives and they seem pretty awesome. I ran into a problem though:

I need to pass an array of images into a directive so I can filter them by certain criteria. Here's my html invoking the directive:

```
<img cover="{{challenge.images}}">
```

This is my directive:

```
myproject.directive('cover', function() {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            console.debug("attrs.cover", Array(attrs.cover));
        }
    };
});
```

The output is a String. is there a way to prevent attr turning into a String?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you don't want to create isolated scope, so:

```
myproject.directive('cover', function($parse) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            var covers = $parse(attrs.cover)($scope);
            console.debug("attrs.cover", covers);
        }
    };
});
```

and then use the directive like so:

```
<img cover="challenge.images">
```

Comment: you can also use $scope.$eval(attrs.cover)

Comment: If you also want to have a string option in the same directive, e.g. 
`<img cover="img/somwewhere.jpg">`
you can set

`var covers = $parse(attrs.cover)($scope) || attrs.cover;`